# How do I save an inkPicture as an image using VBA for Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I am creating an Excel 2013 spreadsheet that needs to capture client and employee signatures. I am able to add inkPicture controls onto a VBA form and the signature action is working. I want to make it so that after the two people sign the inkPictures on the form, their signatures are saved as images on the worksheet. After that, the code will lock up the worksheet.

I am developing this on a workstation, but it will be used on tablets. From what I can see, inkPicture controls don't display on the worksheet on non-mobile versions of the OS (or maybe  it's Excel?). My employer hasn't gotten me a tablet yet, so I can't tell what happens on the tablet. But that's why I'm looking to save the signatures in image controls on the worksheet.

I don't think I can use commercial signature packages, from what I can see, these lock up the entire file, not just single worksheets.

I have seen quite a few articles around the web, but they all seem to use VB.NET or C#.NET and I haven't been able to translate those examples into VBA. Again, the issue is: how to save the inkPicture strokes onto an image on the worksheet? Thanks!

Sorry  don't have any code to show here, I did some work on this in the office, but I'm posting this from home (yes, on my day off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out how to save the signature as a .gif file. But I couldn't load the image file back into the Image control on the worksheet. What you see below is how I got the image itself onto the worksheet. But later, I decided to add the image to a button control instead. Here goes...

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    Dim imgBytes() As Byte
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim newImg
    '
    ' The real piece I was missing!
    '
    imgBytes = inkClient.Ink.Save(IPF_GIF)
    '
    ' Now save the byte array to a file
    '
    strFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.gif"
    Open strFileName For Binary Access Write As #1
    Put #1, 1, imgBytes
    Close #1
    '
    ' Bring the image back onto the sheet, then adjust it as needed
    '
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=strSheetPassword
    Set newImg = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFileName)
    With newImg
        .Top = 100
        .Left = 1000
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strSheetPassword
    '
    ' Code to remove the saved file goes here
    '
    '   ...
    '
    Hide     ' Hiding the form
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this posting! I just bought a Surface and wanted to learn more about inking.

I think an easier way to accomplish what you are looking to do is:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=strSheetPassword
inkClient.Ink.ClipboardCopy
ActiveSheet.paste
   Set newImg = Selection
   With newImg
      .Top = 100
      .Left = 1000
   End With
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=strSheetPassword
```